# Returning multiple components results in a libART error

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

I am using the `react-native-chart` module to display charts in my app, and I wanted to add a touchable functionality to the the plotted dots on the chart, so I went into the library and tried to wrap this with a `<TouchableOpacity>` component: https://github.com/tomauty/react-native-chart/blob/master/src/LineChart.js#L168

When I tried running my app, I get these errors from xcode:

[image]

[image]

#### Reproduction

By Installing the `react-native-chart` module directly from github, then trying to wrap this with TouchableOpacity https://github.com/tomauty/react-native-chart/blob/master/src/LineChart.js#L168

```
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
                <Surface width={containerWidth} height={containerHeight}>
                    { multipleLines }
                    { multipleFills }
                </Surface>
            </View>
            <View style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
                <Surface width={containerWidth} height={containerHeight} />
            </View>
            {(() => {
                if (!this.props.showDataPoint) return null;

                var multipleDataPoints = dataPoints.map( (dataPointSet, index) => {
                    let totalDataSet = dataPointSet.map((d, i) => {
                        return (
                            // <TouchableOpacity>
                              <Circle key={i} {...d} onPress={()=>alert(i)} />
                            // </TouchableOpacity>
                        );
                    });
                    return totalDataSet;
                });

                return (
                    <Surface width={containerWidth} height={containerHeight}>
                        { multipleDataPoints }
                    </Surface>
                );
            })()}
        </View>
    );
```

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 0.39.2
- Platform: iOS
- Operating System: MacOSX 10.12.2

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add Circle component inside TouchableOpacity. ReactArt expects Surface component children to be instance ARTNode in native side. You can try sending [pandresponder](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/panresponder.html) properties to Circle component. From reading core code, it seems that should work. I haven't tried it on ReactArt by myself yet.

Comment: I'm guessing I can't pass any other component with that Circle component in that code? for example if I want to pass a `<Popover>` with that `<Circle>` component so that each plotted dot would have some sort of label, I wouldn't be able to do that?

Comment: I haven't check it. But it seems like you can add any kind of component within Shapes component as children . Only Surface component seems to have have this restriction. Also there is different Text shape in React Native art as well. Please do let me know what worked.

Comment: I added just a simple `<Text>` component inside the `<Circle>` and edited that file so that it would display it's children, although there are no error, the text does not show up, I may be doing something completely wrong, but I just want to render something alongside the Circle object.

Comment: I think you are using Text component, Within ReactNativeArt there is another Text Component, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/ART/ReactNativeART.js#L484 which can work.

Comment: Thanks for that, I tired it out with the ART version, ran it with no error but no Text to be found unfortunately. Though, I was testing with `<Text>`, what if I wanted other 3rd party components to be rendered? the reason I want to do so is so that I have some data that this library has, that I am not sure I can access from my index file, I asked this yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497070/accessing-variable-from-library-to-use-in-component , Interested to see the Text work as well however.

Comment: You should try getting help on react native facebook group. I think there you will get bette resolution. Please atleast upvote, if initial answer was helpful.