# Accessing variable from library to use in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this bit of code right here:

```
                    <Chart // this Component has the value I want
                          style={[styles.chart]}
                          data={this.props.daily}
                          verticalGridStep={6}
                          type="line"
                          showDataPoint={true}
                          color={['white']}
                          gridColor={'white'}
                          dataPointColor={['white']}
                          dataPointFillColor={['white']}
                          axisLabelColor={'white'}
                          axisColor={'white'}
                          chartTitle={'Weekly View'}
                          tightBounds
                          yAxisShortLabel
                          animationDuration={0}
                       />
                  <Popover // I want to use it in here
                     isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
                     fromRect={{x: 197.14285714285714-20, y: 10, width: 0, height: 0}}
                     onClose={this.closePopover}
                     placement={'bottom'}
                     key={i}
                    >
                     <Text>Value</Text>
                    </Popover>
```

The goal is to set this popover in the exact location of the plotted dots form that chart, I found the area in the code for the library that has the coordinates of the dots in an array:

```
var multipleDataPoints = dataPoints.map( (dataPointSet, index) => {
                        console.log(dataPointSet)                 //HERE
                        let totalDataSet = dataPointSet.map((d, i) => {
                            return (
                                        <Circle key={i} {...d} onPress={()=> console.log("\N\N\NYOYOYO")}>
                                            <Text>What</Text>
                                        </Circle>
                            );
                        });
                        return totalDataSet;
                    });
```

What I was wondering, is there a way to access that variable from the library so I can use it in the `<Popover>` component in the index file so I can set the location of it relative to the plotted dots?

Comment: You can add a ref to the component and try to access this var. Have you tried this ?

Comment: @GuilhermeHerzog I have not, how would I got about doing this in this specific case?